# Need to sort based on the following conditions

Tags: c#, linq

1. State which have maximum vowels should come First.
2. If No of vowels are same , then

   - Check for length of state name and which have maximum length put it
     first.
   - If length is also same, then sort based upon first character of state
     name.
   - If first character is also same, then place according to their
     occurrence in the list.

here is the code

```
Public static void Main(string[] args)
{

     List<ClsState> states = new List<ClsState>();
     states.Add(new ClsState("Gujarat"));
     states.Add(new ClsState("Maharashtra"));
     states.Add(new ClsState("Punjab"));
     states.Add(new ClsState("AndhraPradesh"));
     states.Add(new ClsState("Telengana"));
     var result = states.OrderBy(a => a.StateName.Length)
                        .ThenBy(a => a.StateName);

 }
```

Comment: You requirements are a four level sort, but you have only two sort criteria.

Comment: Use the OrderBy - Comparer (https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/SQL-Ordering-Operators-050af19e) and use your custom comparer(add your logic in your custom comarer class).

Comment: In don't think this is a bad question, but it would help to see sample outputs that demonstrate your use cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<ClsState> states = new List<ClsState>
        {
            new ClsState("Gujarat"),
            new ClsState("Maharashtra"),
            new ClsState("Punjab"),
            new ClsState("AndhraPradesh"),
            new ClsState("Telengana"),
        };

        var vowls = new List<char> { 'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u', 'y', 'A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U', 'Y' };
        var sorted = states
            .Select(s => new Tuple<int, ClsState>(s.StateName.ToCharArray().Where(l => vowls.Contains(l)).Count(), s))
            .OrderByDescending(i => i.Item1)
            .ThenByDescending(i => i.Item2.StateName.Length)
            .ThenBy(i => i.Item2.StateName[0])
            .ThenByDescending(i => states.Where(s => s.StateName == i.Item2.StateName).Count());
    }
```

As asked in comment, below printing the names:

```
    foreach(var state in sorted)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(state.Item2.StateName);
    }
```

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? It sorts by number of vowels (from highest number to lowest). Then by length (from longest to shortest). Then by first letter (ascending: from a to z). Finally by how many times it occurs in collection.

Comment: dont mind pls mak it sure for printing on console screen i tried ...like   foreach (var item in sorted)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(sorted.FirstOrDefault());

            }

Comment: You have to access the item in the `Tuple` to print it. I added it in the edit

Comment: sorry it is not sorting.... If length is also same, then sort based upon first character of state name.

Comment: sorry it is not sorting....based on condition  If length is also same, then sort based upon first character of state name. –

Comment: It's done in this line `.ThenBy(i => i.Item2.StateName[0])` If you want to change the order to descending use ThenByDescending. Basically adjust the parameters according to what you need.

Comment: if u update Maharashtra as Maharashtraii then andrapradesh should come first as both andrapradesh  and Maharashtraii have sam number of vowels

Comment: but Maharashtraii  is coming first

Comment: In Maharashtraii I see 6 vowels and in andrapradesh I see 4. So Maharashtraii should be first.

Comment: Adding and subtracting is not that difficult. I understand you can have a problem with linq. But at least analyze the code that submitted to you. And debug the result yourself first.